# Move files between branch folders in Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying, through my pipeline, to copy a file that is at the root of my branch to a folder inside the branch itself.

The pipeline gives no error, but the file is not copied.

See below.

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    Contents: '**.pbix'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/publicar'
```

Result:

```
Starting: CopyFiles
==============================================================================
Task         : Copy files
Description  : Copy files from a source folder to a target folder using patterns matching file paths (not folder paths)
Version      : 2.209.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files
==============================================================================
found 1 files
Copying /home/vsts/work/1/s/example2.pbix to /home/vsts/work/1/s/publicar/example2.pbix
Finishing: CopyFiles
```

What could possibly be wrong?

I'm trying, through my pipeline, to copy a file that is at the root of my branch to a folder inside the branch itself.

The pipeline gives no error, but the file is not copied.

Comment: What leads you to believe it's not being copied?

Comment: At the end of the process, the file is not in the destination folder.

Comment: How have you confirmed that? The output says it is. Perhaps it would be useful if you took a step back and explained what your ultimate goal is here. **Why** are you copying this file? What is the purpose of the copy?

Comment: My goal is to move the file to another folder. The folder the file is in is used by the pipeline to publish that file itself to Power BI. Initially I copy the file to the artifact and soon after I need to move it to another folder, because if I don't, in the next pipeline, other files will be in the folder and will be republished without need.

Comment: Are you under the impression that copying files is somehow updating the location of the files in version control? If so, that is an incorrect impression. During the pipeline run, everything is happening against a temporary copy (i.e. a `clone`) of the repository. Nothing is changed in the repository or pushed back to the repository after the pipeline is complete.

Comment: So it's not possible to copy the file to a folder inside the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirement, you need to copy the file to a folder and then update the Repository via Azure Pipeline.

When you only use Copy Files task to copy the file, it will work on the agent level and will not sync the Azure Repo.

In this case, you can keep using copy files task to copy the file. Then you can add additional steps to run git command to update the Repository.

Here is an example:

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)'
    Contents: '**.pbix'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/publicar'

- script: |
   git config --global user.email "Emailaddress"
   git config --global user.name "Kevin Lu"
   git add .
   git commit -m "Update folder"
   git push origin main
  workingDirectory: $(build.sourcesdirectory)
```

You can use the command: `persistCredentials: true` to keep the  Repo credential during the agent job.

At the same time, you need to grant the **Contribute** permission for **Build Service Account** .

For example:

[image]

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Run Git commands in a script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)